# How to download Abbyy FineReader Engine

Tags: ocr, abbyy, finereader

We are very new to Abby Fine Reader. We would need to do some customization to read the recognized text. For that we have tried to download the Abbyy Fine Reader Engine trail, but the link always navigate us to Cloud OCR SDK page. Please help us to find the way to download the Abbyy FineReader Engine to try it through .Net programming language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

FineReader Engine SDK requires a direct contact to your local ABBYY office.  Trial is not distributed online for downloading.

Based on your previous post, there may be more effective solutions than the FineReader or the Engine SDK.  Please feel free to contact me privately and I can share our experience with integrations using various ABBYY packages.

Comment: @IIya: Thanks for your response. I've reached you at ilyae@wisetrend.com with the subject of 'OCR SDK from StackOverflow'. Kindly check the same.